A custom function with bootstrap to estimate 95% confidence interval in R
A few days ago, I asked a question about how to bootstrap glm regression, estimate 95% confidence interval, and jay.sf helped. Here is the codes:
library(ggplot2)

 df <- transform(
   data.frame(Conc=runif(200, min=200, max=1000)),
   AE=rbinom(200, 1, prob=plogis((Conc - 600)/100))
 )

 fit <- glm(AE ~ Conc, family='binomial', data=df)
 ndf <- data.frame(Conc=seq(min(df$Conc), max(df$Conc), length.out=1e3))
 pred <- predict(fit, newdata=ndf, type='link')

 set.seed(42)
 bf <- replicate(
   999L, {
     bdf <- df[sample.int(nrow(df), replace=TRUE), ]
     glm(AE ~ Conc, family='binomial', data=bdf)
   },
   simplify=FALSE
 )

 bpred <- sapply(bf, predict, newdata=ndf, type='link')

 ci <- \(x, sd) x + as.matrix(sd*(-qt(.025, Inf))) %*% cbind(-1, 1)
 bpredci <- ci(matrixStats::rowMeans2(bpred), matrixStats::rowSds(bpred))

 ggplot(data = ndf) +
   geom_line(aes(Conc, fit$family$linkinv(pred)))+
   geom_ribbon( aes(Conc, 
                  ymin = fit$family$linkinv(bpredci[, 1]),
                  ymax = fit$family$linkinv(bpredci[, 2])
                    ),
              fill = "grey", alpha = 0.5)

Now, I want to write a custom function.
According to Gregor Thomas and Edward's comments, I modified the codes.
library(ggplot2)

   df <- transform(data.frame(
     Conc=runif(200, min=200, max=1000)),
     AE=rbinom(200, 1, prob=plogis((Conc - 600)/100)))

mf = function(mydata, x, y){

 fit <- glm(as.formula(paste(y, "~", x)),family='binomial', data=mydata)
 ndf <- mydata %>% select(x)
 pred <- predict(fit, newdata=ndf, type='link') 


 set.seed(42)
 bf <- replicate(
   999L, {
     bdf <- mydata[sample.int(nrow(mydata), replace=TRUE), ]
     glm(as.formula(paste(y, "~", x)),family='binomial',  data=bdf)
   },
   simplify=FALSE
 )


 bpred <- sapply(bf, predict, newdata=ndf, type='link')


 ci <- \(mea, sd) mea + as.matrix(sd*(-qt(.025, Inf))) %*% cbind(-1, 1)
 bpredci <- ci(matrixStats::rowMeans2(bpred), matrixStats::rowSds(bpred))

 ggplot(ndf) +
   geom_line(aes(.data[[x]], fit$family$linkinv(pred))) +
   geom_ribbon(aes(.data[[x]],
                  ymin = fit$family$linkinv(bpredci[, 1]),
                  ymax = fit$family$linkinv(bpredci[, 2])),
              fill = "grey",
              alpha = 0.5,
              inherit.aes = FALSE)
}

mf(mydata = df, "Conc", "AE")

I modified the codes with your comments, and deleted the error codes directly. Finally, it works now.

I don't think {{ works inside formulas. If you define foo <- function(data, x, y) lm({{y}} ~ {{x}}, data) and try foo(mtcars, mpg, cyl) you get a similar error. I've marked this as a duplicate of a question about working with formula objects.

fit <- eval(substitute(glm(y ~ x, family='binomial', data=data)))

Also, be careful with the naming and ordering of your function arguments. "family" comes before "data", which you haven't named, and that's bad practice.

@Edward That's a point, edited that in my answer. Note, however, that formula= element isn't named. But agree either correct argument order or naming all of them.

Dylan, you've also got Con instead of Conc in 1 or 2 places.

@GregorThomas, I have removed {{ in formulas, it's another error now.

@Edward, Yes. And x is Conc. I don't know how to set  x as a new column name of ndf, and I thought this column name has no effect, so I write it as Con.

When you use data[[x]] you are treating x as if it is a string, "Conc". When you do {{x}} or eval(substitute(...x...)) you are using x as an unquoted object Conc. x can't be both of those at once--you have to pick one way to call your function and one way to use x. Personally, I find strings easier to work with so I would use mdf(df, "Conc", "AE") which would mean skipping the eval/substitute and instead use glm(as.formula(paste(y, "~", x)), ... and keep using data[[x]]  and use the .data[[x]] paradigm for ggplot.

@GregorThomas , thank you. I edited my codes according to your comments, and it works. Actually I simplify one sentence ndf <- data.frame(Conc = seq(200, 1000, length.out=1e3)), and if I write it as ndf <- data.frame(x = seq(min(df[[x]]), max(df[[x]]), length.out=1e3)) , it still cannot run.
